# Optimizing reactive blaze with fetch

Tags: sorting, dom, meteor, meteor-blaze

When using a cursor to render, one of the nice features with Blaze is that it automatically connects each field in the dom to each field in the collection, making each dom collection element reactive. This minimizes screen redrawing.

But unfortunately, for my app, I have to do a lot of sorting of my collection in the client before rendering the display. This means that I must do a fetch of all the data to be displayed into the client, sort it, then display it. Fetch breaks field-based reactivity, and causes my app to refetch all the data on each change in the collection.

Is there a recommended way of handling this so that I can make my rendering more responsive to changes within individual docs in my collection, without having to refresh the whole collection each time?

I am thinking that there might be a way of observing changes on the collection then using jquery to make the appropriate changes to my dom instead. Has anyone tried this as an optimization technique? Any suggestions?

Comment: You should see the same performance characteristics as using a cursor if you return an array of fetched documents where each document has an id. Is that not what you observed?

Comment: DW, When any one doc in a collection is changed, it refetches and redisplays the whole array of docs. This is because I use fetch. Without fetch it would only redisplay the changed doc. I'm wondering if anyone has used observeChanges and jquery in a case like this to improve performance, and does it significantly improve the performance.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, a Meteor cursor is required for an optimal reactive rendering of the #each loop.

If you get your items from a Meteor publication, you can sort them on the client without fetching, so it doesn't cause any unnecessary re-rendering.

```
var myItems = new Mongo.Collection('myItems');
Meteor.subscribe('myItems');

Template.myItems.helpers({
  getMyItems: function () {
    return myItems.find({}, {sort: [['myField', 'asc']]});
  }
});
```

If your data comes from other sources such as an external REST API, or if the data is created on the client, you can store the data in a local mini mongo collection instead of a regular JS array on the client in order to get your Meteor cursor for the #each loop.

```
var myItems = new Mongo.Collection(null);
var dataReceived = [{myField: 'item1'}, {myField: 'item2'}, {myField: 'item3'}];
for (i in dataReceived) {
  myItems.insert(dataFromOtherSource[i]);
}

Template.myItems.helpers({
  getMyItems: function () {
    return myItems.find({}, {sort: [['myField', 'asc']]});
  }
});
```

Now you can insert, remove or edit the data in 'myItems' and only the changed part of the data is re-rendered. Also, I'd suppose, you can change the sorting parameters in the Template helper and the rendering will still be optimal.

Comment: Your first suggestion makes sense, except that my sorts, and sometimes my search parameters are too complex to be expressed in the find query. I have to pull a superset of the records, then filter them in code, then sort the results before displaying them.

If I could pull my superset of records into a temporary collection, filter and sort the collection before displaying, then that might work; but I suspect that I would lose the reactivity from the original client database in the process.

Comment: If Mongo can't do the filtering and sorting, I guess you lose the optimal #each re-rendering whenever you recalculate the items of your temporary collection. But at least your solution would retain optimal rendering in cases where only the mongo query for the temporary collection is changed. I'm interested in knowing what you end up with.

Comment: Thanks. I'm now thinking that i can use observe and write to a temporary collection that I then filter and sort on the client. Because I am using observe  I should be able to draw optimized from the temporary collection to the display, and I may be able to optimize the whole process. I'll let you know if I develop a working solution.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I think I have a plan:

I will use observe on my collection, and also keep an extra temporary local collection. The temporary local collection only needs the _ids of the original docs I intend to display, but filtered and sorted. When observe events come in I can use JS to add, remove or rearrange the appropriate ids within the temporary collection.

The template would use a cursor on the temporary collection using forEach for efficiency. And every helper for the template would uses the _id from the temporary collection to access the main collection for display.

Comment: No problem. Sounds like a smart solution!